# Python script has been built to exe, but how to make it not show the command prompt?

Tags: python, exe, command-prompt

I have converted the python script into the exe version. But every time i executed it, it will show the command prompt. Is it possible to change the script to make it not show the command prompt?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use cx_freeze?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `.py` file extension to `.pyw`
And then add `Win32GUI` to your script.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"


setup(
        name = u"XXX",
        version = "1.0",
        description = u"XXX",
        options = {'build_exe': {'include_files':includefiles}},
        executables = [Executable("XXXX.pyw" ,base = base)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! if the system is win64, should I just change to "win64"? coz i changed that, but it seems not working since it still show the command prompt

Comment: I don't know,you could try 'win32' and 'win64'.

Comment: I tried both win32 and win64, both not working...@Aaron